# CPU Upgrade Issue

Tags: upgrade, hardware, cpu

Is it possible to upgrade CPU (ex: from AMD Athlon II X2 to Phenom II X4) without any problems? I means just replacing the old cpu with new cpu at same socket and booting ubuntu with any problems or changing something.

Comment: It should be as simple as that. Any problems you experience would more likely be caused by hardware conflicts :)

Comment: Thank you, what about the some features that are not supported in Athlon II but available in Phenom II. Can Ubuntu automatically detect them?

Comment: Before you buy a new CPU check with your motherboard's specs if it is supported. You may also need to upgrade your BIOS **before** you plug in the new CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu generates *most* of its hardware configuration dynamically on boot. There are set configurations and overrides (udev stores hardware names so things are consistent between boots, and network configurations can be made to be hardware-specific) but these shouldn't cause terminal issues.

Even the graphics stack is separated out and dynamic these days but you are more likely to run into issues in this area. Again, not terminal issues - just ones that require you to remove the old driver. And that's only in *some* scenarios.

In short, Ubuntu doesn't care what CPU you're running, as long as it's compatible (which in your case, it is).

Comment: What about If I replace the set of cpu consists of new motherboard, new chipset and new cpu, is it still possible run properly?

Comment: @obysr Shouldn't make much of a difference. I can't say for certain whether you'll see any problems but I can say: it's a hell of a lot more robust than Windows ever was at hardware upgrades.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But, I don't understand last sentence you writed. What does it mean? Sorry I am a non native english language, I'm an Indonesian. English is very difficult to me. T_T

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there should be no problem, especially since the rest of your hardware stays the same.

Comment: Thank you, have you tried it?

What about the some features that are not supported in Athlon II but available in Phenom II. Can Ubuntu automatically detect them?

Comment: I have tried it successfully and those features should be automatically detected.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the motherboard and chipset support that processor, there should be zero changes to the operating system (Ubuntu). The instructions will still be computed the same way.

Comment: What if I get new motherboard with new chipset and new processor? Is it still possible?

Comment: A new motherboard would likely have a different chipset and may have a different socket. You'd need to make sure the socket type and chipset support the processor you want. A new motherboard may mean different memory architecture too. If your system is a few years old, it may use DDR2 memory. A new motherboard may only have DDR3 slots. If the new processor is compatible with your existing chipset you should be good to go.